# Реализовать страницы в winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

В окно из бд загружаются данные.Но нужно сделать чтобы загрузилось не все сразу.А сделать страницы и на странице по несколько штук (как на сайтах с объявлениями например).есть переключатель снизустраница которая сейчас открыта следующая предыдущая и последняя.Как это можно реализовать в формах?какие есть элементы для этого?

Comment: Вроде, из коробки ничего нет. Вам предстоит написать собственный пейджер и динамически создавать контролы(страницы) на форме.

Comment: С чем именно у вас проблема: с реализацией GUI, с составлением sql-запроса или с расстановкой запятых?

Comment: а что за данные как выглядят и как вывести хотите